# HTML5 Section or Article

Tags: html, semantic-markup, semantic-html

Let's say I have this part of my website (project to make a webshop):

```
<section id="GraphicsCards">
        <h2>Graphics Cards</h2>
        <section>
            <h3>Radeon GPUs</h3>
            <section>
                <h4>ASUS Dual Radeon RX 7800 XT OC</h4>
                <p>1x HDMI, 3x DisplayPort, RDNA 3</p>
                <img src="../media/GPUs/rx7800xt.png" alt="rx7800xt">
                <p class="price">Price: € 549.00</p>
                <a href="./p_RX7800_details.html">More details</a>
            </section>
        </section>

        <section>
            <h3>Nvidia GPUs</h3>
            <section>
                <h4>GIGABYTE GeForce RTX 4060 EAGLE OC 8G</h4>
                <p>2x HDMI, 2x DisplayPort, DLSS 3</p>
                <img src="../media/GPUs/rtx4060.png" alt="rtx4060">
                <p class="price">Price: € 349.00</p>
                <p>More details</p>
            </section>
        </section>
    </section>
```

Would there be any use in changing any of them in articles or should I just keep them as is? I'm still a bit confused as to which one I should use.

Researched a bit but still quite confused, I can use both but I want to make sure it's properly made so that when I continue working on it and use CSS it can be properly designed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `<section>` and `<article>` behave exactly like `<div>` tags. So for styling with CSS it makes no difference at all which of them (or other [div-like elements](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/semantic-html-alternatives-to-using-divs/)) you use.

But they are what's called [semantic HTML elements](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp), so they convey a meaning. Which matters for

- readability of one's code (to developers)
- accessiblity (to visually impaired people who use screen readers)
- SEO (search engine crawlers can better understand what your site is about)

According to [W3C](https://www.w3.org/) (who develops the HTML standard):

> The **section** element represents a section of a document, typically with a title or heading. ~ [Link](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20121025/section.html)

> The **article** element represents a section of content that forms an independent part of a document or site; for example, a magazine or newspaper article, or a blog entry. ~ [Link](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20121025/article.html)

In your case the two outer `<section>` elements make perfect sense, but you could turn the innermost `<section>`s into `<article>`s, because as products they're somewhat self-contained and independent.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks a ton! That's the kind of answer I was looking for. I figured the actual products themselves would've been a good fit for articles.

Comment: @Maxime This answer is pretty identical to mine, which I posted 10 minutes before this answer was posted. When there are equivalent answers, it's expected that you accept the answer that was posted first.

Comment: It's also incorrect and misleading to say "technically there's no difference" between the two elements. There are distinct technical differences between the two.

Comment: @Sean I used the word *technically* to make the understanding easier that it **behaves the same functionally** (and differs only semantically, i.e. in a non-functional way). But thanks for the remark, I removed the possible misunderstanding. ;)

Comment: @Sean your answer is absolutely not identical, indeed very different because you missed both questions that the OP posed: (1) would there be any use in changing tags? (what does it affect? users? devs? crawlers? ...? Why is it important?) and (2) if it can be styled with CSS just fine. You only explained the difference between the two tags and gave a recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between a `<section>` and an `<article>` is that the latter...

> ...represents a self-contained composition in a document, page, application, or site, which is intended to be independently distributable or reusable (e.g., in syndication). Examples include: a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, or a blog entry, a product card, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content.
>
> — [MDN Web Docs: The Article Contents element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article)

**What you have now is great as-is.**

Or if you intend for the individual specification to independently distributable or reusable, you could convert those innermost `<section>` elements to `<article>` elements. Both approaches are valid HTML and semantically reasonable. In this case it is somewhat of a judgement call by you as the author.

Personally, since those specification blocks are self-contained and could make complete sense if they were clipped out of the page to stand alone, I'd lean towards using an `<article>`. But this is up to interpretation and author intent.

But don't double up and have an article that only has a section as its one child or vice versa. You can mix them, but don't double wrap something in order to use both.